# AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I have been working on an Audio Application where a user can record and play the recorded audio file. In my app during recording a user can pause the recording and play it to listen what he has recorded and then again he can continue the recording.

So now my question is that if a user have recorded a 20 seconds audio and when he plays the audio and wants to resume recording from over 10 seconds overlapping/discarding the next 10 seconds audio. ?

I have looked into the AVAudioRecorder documentation and there is not property to set the duration of the recorder to start recording from specific time. So please someone tell me if it is possible or not. ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please improve grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there’s an easier solution, but you may want to look at [`AVMutableComposition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can easily create an empty mutable composition, insert the recorded sound into an audio track and then edit the track as needed – delete segments, add another recording, etc.

Comment: can we consider that it is not possible to playback a paused recording?It needs to stopped